# Python implementation of BLAST alignment algorithm?

Tags: python, alignment, blast

Is anyone aware of a pure python implementation of BLAST alignment?  I am trying to study this algorithm...

Comment: For those of us who aren't computational biologists: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST

Answer (score 3):

In fact a complete implementation of the BLAST algorithm is a quite hard. It has a lot of steps and optimizations. What could you do is: take a look of the BLAST Book from O'Reilly, for a very good explanation, take a look of the NCBI Blast code base, that it is big and hard to understand at the first glace, or, I sugest you to take a look at other BLAST implementation or may be, others algorithms like BLAT and Genoogle (http://genoogle.pih.bio.br/)

Answer (score -1):

Try looking into BioPython:

http://biopython.org/

http://github.com/JoaoRodrigues/biopython/tree/GSOC2010

Comment: No, biopython does not implement Blast, it calls the canonical ncbi BLAST executable program that has to be installed independly